# c# compiler returning error not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

```
get
{
    string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string pathName;
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("TradeBotData");
    if (!d.Exists)
    {
        if (d.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Plugins")
        {
            d.Create();
            return d.FullName;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (d.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Plugins")
        {
            return d.FullName;
        }
        else
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Data path Fallback!!!");
            pathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, @"\TradeBotData");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
            Console.WriteLine("Created Save Folder At: {0} :", pathName);
            return pathName;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure why this happens. I think that all code paths return a value because I have `if` and `else`. 
If I insert `return "";` into the code it just returns ""; infinitely.

Please advise.

Comment: you have to return something when `if (d.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Plugins")` fails.

Comment: To expand Hari's comment: In the case where the directory doesn't exist, so you're going into the body of the first `if` statment; if the parent name isn't `Plugins`, you then don't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `DirectoryInfo` doesn't exist, the compiler will check if `d.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Plugins"` if it is, the code withing the `if` statement will be executed **but otherwise the compiler will throw an exception: "not all code path return a value" because you don't return anything**.

So you are missing a `return` here:

```
get
{
string dirName =System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string pathName;
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("TradeBotData");
    if (!d.Exists)
    {
        if (d.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Plugins")
        {
            d.Create();
            return d.FullName;
        }
     //////////HERE///////
    }
    else
    {
        if (d.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Plugins")
        {
            return d.FullName;
        }
        else
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Data path Fallback!!!");
            pathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, @"\TradeBotData");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
            Console.WriteLine("Created Save Folder At: {0} :", pathName);
            return pathName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What the op want to do, to solve this issue?

Comment: un-lucky I'm not sure what you mean..

Comment: You have identified the issue, To make it a perfect answer you need to suggest solution for him

Comment: @user3378165 Along with providing solution, explain what is wrong how that can be fixed (some details).

Comment: Thank you for the great comments, you are totally right, I will edit my answer to include an explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize pathName to empty string. Then set it in your if/else logic and in the and of `get` just return it:

```
  get
            {
              string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
              string pathName = String.Empty;
              DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("TradeBotData");
              if (!d.Exists) {
                if (d.Parent.Name == "Plugins") {
                  d.Create();
                  pathName = d.FullName;
                }
              } else {
                if (d.Parent.Name == "Plugins") {
                  pathName = d.FullName;
                } else {
                  Console.WriteLine("Data path Fallback!!!");
                  pathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, @"\TradeBotData");
                  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
                  Console.WriteLine("Created Save Folder At: {0} :", pathName);

                }
              }

              return pathName;
            }
```